# In which soundtrack album can I find "Virgin Road Ni Hana Ga Saku"?

Tags: theme-song, music, youre-under-arrest

File 23 of the first season of You're Under Arrest (Taiho Shichauzo) featured the wedding of Daimaru (Ken's father) and Sena. I have found that the song used there that caught my interest has the same title as the episode; that is, "Virgin Road Ni Hana Ga Saku" (ヴァージンロードに花が咲く).

I have tried searching among the various soundtrack albums released for You're Under Arrest, but it seems the version of "Virgin Road" in those albums is the version sung by Kakijima Shinji, instead of the version heard in the episode (which featured a chorus of voices, among other things).

Thus, my question: which album has the **full version** of "Virgin Road" that was sung by the same guys who sung the version in the episode?

Answer (score 2):

You can get it in [*You're Under Arrest Full Throttle* 5 Disc](http://vgmdb.net/album/21787) Set ([逮捕しちゃうぞ フルスロットル 5枚駆動! 全曲教習!!](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E9%80%AE%E6%8D%95%E3%81%97%E3%81%A1%E3%82%83%E3%81%86%E3%81%9E-%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%83%AB%E4%BC%81%E7%94%BB-5%E6%9E%9A%E9%A7%86%E5%8B%95-%E5%85%A8%E6%9B%B2%E6%95%99%E7%BF%92-TV%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9/dp/tracks/B00120VGZU/ref=dp_tracks_all_3#disc_3)), on Track 8 of Disc 3.